# Python disable while iterating

Tags: python, loops, memory, data-structures, iteration

So I am creating a data structure that is based on storage and memory. Lets say I have the following method:

```
def __store(self):
    #stores information into self.__memory list
```

now what I want to do is, if this function is called inside a loop, I want it to be called **only after the loop is finished**

## My reasons

This method gets called in many other methods, most importantly `__setitem__` so take a look at the following code:

```
for i in xrange(100):
    class[i] = i + 5
```

right now, this will store the information up until the loop finished (100 times), but I only want it to store the information after the loop finishes.

## question

essentially I just need to be able to stop a function from running if iteration is going on in the program, and then execute once the iteration is done.

**how can I do that?**

## extra info

This data structure is a dictionary that has many functions for memory.

The kind of full-storage memory that I am storing with `__store` is for the purpose of undoing . Anything in a loop would have no need for an undo because, until the loop is over, the user should not need to undo anything.

This memory is based on control, so anything inside iteration should not be stored because there is no need for the actual memory.

That is why I would not like to store during iteration, but, if something that requires storage is run inside iteration, I would like it to run after the iteration it was inside completes.

Comment: Detecting if it's being called from within some outer iteration sounds like a hard problem, but using a buffer that flushes after it reaches a certain size is a tried-and-true approach to a similar problem – it won't prevent the buffer from flushing within a loop, but it will flush less often.

Comment: You can learn a great deal about CPython's internals, and use some of the obscure introspection features to disassemble the byte code and deduce whether a loop is in progress in any function "up the call stack" - but that would be insane ;-)  There is no straightforward way to do this.

Comment: @kojiro I am not trying to flush it in the loop...I am trying to not run a function until after the loop is finished. This will keep all previous memory stored, but just not overload it with unnecessary memory.

Comment: @TimPeters insane is fine by me, I just need some direction as how to go about this

Comment: @RyanSaxe, give it up - it's a dead end.  For all you know, it's being called from (e.g.) a conditional within a `while True:` loop that goes around a billion times, where the conditional only executes twice.  That is, "in a loop" is really irrelevant.  Say more about your actual problem, not this purported "solution".  Then people can guide you to sane approaches ;-)

Comment: *if iteration is going on* – when, in any program of any real size and purpose, is iteration *not* going on?

Comment: @TimPeters I just added info to explain why there should be no storage  while iterating. So a `while True:` should not store anything anyways

Comment: @TimPeters I gotta ask, because it's been driving me crazy for a couple days: Are you _the_ [Tim Peters](http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?TimPeters), of [TimSort](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Timsort) fame?

Comment: @kojiro, yup - although most people ask if I wrote the "Zen of Python" - LOL ;-)

Comment: @kojiro when you are manipulating data in a controlled manner rather than running or creating something or accessing information

Comment: @RyanSaxe You could take the *opposite* of the buffer approach, since you're presumably operating on fast memory – let redundant undos get added whenever, but write an algorithm to "pack" the undo stack periodically to clean up subatomic undo operations.

Comment: redundancy is not my problem though. In the example above, it will have 100 different instances of the datatype added to memory, but the only one that actually matters is the last one at the end of the iteration.

Comment: @RyanSaxe right, so is there any way to tell, at the end of the loop, that they were all added by the same loop? Some characteristic of the objects added, perhaps?

Comment: @kojiro i don't think so because the user writes the loops so I can't tell much since `__iter__` will only help me if the user is looping through the actual instance. but that idea is perfect. If at the end of every loop it makes it a tuple, you can compress the tuple by a unique id!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A function behave difference while inside a loop is a bad idea, try to use `context manager` instead. it is a better way to do so and it is easier to understand. 
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/

For example:

```
with sqlite3.connect(":memory:") as conn:
    # update will hold in transaction.
    for i in xrange(100):
        conn.execute("insert ....")

pass
# sqlite3 will commit now
```

In the same way:

```
with a() as b:
    # data won't store
    for i in xrange(100):
        # don't store data
        b[i] = i + 5

pass
# data store while leave context
```

## EDIT 1

ContextManager has **enter**, and **exit** method will

```
class MemoryManager(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.cache = {}
        self.buffer = False

    def __enter__(self):
        self.buffer = True

    def __store(self):
        # store data
        pass

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        self.cache[key] = value
        if not self.buffer:
            self.__store()

    def __exit__(self, exc_type, exc_value, traceback):
        self.__store()
        self.buffer = False
```

Therefore

```
m = MemoryManager()
with m as b:
    # __enter__ got called, set the manager to buffer mode
    # data won't store
    for i in xrange(100):
        # don't store data
        m[i] = i + 5    # in with block, so __store won't be called

pass
# __exit__ got called, __store automatically and leave buffer mode
m[0] = 10  # not in buffer mode, __store will be called
```

Comment: wait, when you say "don't store data", do you mean that the line wont execute? because I need the dictionary to change through the entire loop, but I simply have a function that gets called when `__setitem__` is called and I don't want that function to be called during the loop. does that mak sense

Comment: See the example, The line will still be executed. But Context Manager give you ability to detect it is called inside the with block or not. So the line can behave different in the with block.

Comment: okay so this seems like the best solution. It is annoying to require people to write a with block, but it seems like the only way

Comment: @RyanSaxe Have you ever written a programming language? If so, did you provide a way for the coder to disable a function based on context like *are any of my stack frames in a loop or recursive function*? If not, I think your expectations are not only unrealistic, but downright unfair.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first of all: letting a function detect that it is being called from within a loop is kind of ridiculous. Functions that can act on information like that violate pretty much every aspect of the Python Way, and even context-hypersensitive languages like Perl generally avoid introspecting their caller's environment unless specifically intended to do so. You would need so many non-standard interpreter hacks.

Putting that aside, though, I don't think 'being run in a loop' is what you actually want the function to be based on. From your description, you want a multi-step operation to be considered as a single one as far as undo states are concerned, on the basis that it will appear to users to be a single change, which is a perfectly logical reason to want operations to save sometimes and not save other times. But that's not entirely covered by disabling undo history during loops (since your app probably runs in a main loop) or even just during for loops (some algorithms will demand a while loop, and you still want to disable tracking in those). Also, what about the case of calling two different functions that affect the same value in a way that, to the user, appears to be one single operation? You still want to save only one change to that value.

Thus, I think what you really want is to save state *after each user input that changes state*, and default to undo-unaware behavior.